# javascript and ajax issue

Tags: ajax

i want to show a folder. After that clicking on this folder might open some subfolder those are containing the images and at last when one will click on each folder then he/she should see some images which will sliding.

How can do that? any link or suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for a tree control. If you can use jQuery have a look at [TreeView](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/) plug-in.